# Проверка на вхождение элемента в массив

Tags: c#, массивы

Добрый вечер!
Есть двумерный массив `arr` и некорректная проверка на вхождение цифры 1.

```
byte[,] arr = new byte[,]{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}; // массив arr

if (arr.Exists (1)) { // проверка на вхождение

// ...

}
```

Как правильно записать условие?

Comment: Либо просто двойным циклом пройтись по всем элементам и сравнить на равенство. Если нужно много и часто проверять наличие разных элементов, то лучше использовать HashSet для проверок.

Comment: Самый краткий но медленный вариант написания для вашего случая это `foreach (byte b in arr) if (b == 1) {/*Contains!*/}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант с расширяющим методом

```
public static class SquareArrayExtension
{
    public static bool Contains(this byte[,] array, byte value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (value == array[i, j])
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Пользоваться так

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[,] array =
    {
        { 1, 1, 1},
        { 1, 1, 1}
    };

    bool exists = array.Contains(5);

    Console.WriteLine(exists);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Ваш метод Contains строит на каждый запрос заново HashSet. Если уже это делать то проще просто в цикле проверить на равенство и вернуть результат, будет даже быстрее чем с HashSet.

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul, вы правы, здесь можно вполне простым перебором пройтись. Я когда начал писать о HashSet думал поначалу. Потому так и вышло.

Comment: Ну и переменная `result` не нужна, хм или вы просто хотите оставить одну точку выхода? Это неэффективно, делать `break` вложенного цикла, ведь внешний так и продолжит выполнение, лучше уж сразу `return true` тогда...

Comment: @Андрей исправил..., хотя сначала не хотел :)

Comment: Этот способ работает, но не лучше ли использовать один foreach за место двух for?

Comment: @Николай это как раз обсуждалось в др.вопросе. При размерности массива 2 и более используется IEnumerable, а не IEnumerable<T>, следовательно при использовании foreach будет происходить unboxing.

Comment: @Bulson, как выяснилось, всё же foreach не породит упаковку/распаковку, т.к. в компиляторе этот случай отдельно предусмотрен, в отличие от Cast() - который, да, приведет к этим накладным расходам.

Comment: @Николай, так что, лично я бы (если вам интересно мое мнение), взял бы первый вариант из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/737154/218063) - он одинаков по производительности с этим, но более прост

Comment: @Андрей OK буду знать.

Answer (score 6):

Приведите свой массив к IEnumerable и можете использовать Linq:

```
if (arr.Cast<byte>().Any(x => x == 1))
```

Comment: Можно избавиться от лямбды, если использовать `Contains` вместо `Any`

Comment: Правильно понимаю что Linq на каждую проверку внутри просто циклом все элементы обходит и сравнивает/применяет лямбду?

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul сейчас - да: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1287

Comment: К сожалению, этот способ породит упаковку всех элементов массива: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/737194/218063 действовать через foreach выгоднее

Answer (score 4):

Напишу два решения - для случая когда данных достаточно много и когда нужно проверять вхождение много раз, для такого случая наиболее быстрым будет использовать HashSet, а также для случая если массив не большой или запросов не много, для этого достаточно простой проверки циклом.

Вот код на C#, [можно запустить онлайн](https://repl.it/NXSm/2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class ArrayContains
{
    static void Main() {
        byte[,] arr = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
        byte to_check = 3;

        // Простейшее медленное решение.
        foreach (byte b in arr) {
            if (b == to_check) {
                Console.WriteLine("Contains!");
                break;
            }
        }

        // Немного более сложное решение значительно более быстрое.
        HashSet<byte> checker = new HashSet<byte>();
        foreach (byte b in arr) checker.Add(b);
        if (checker.Contains(to_check)) Console.WriteLine("Contains!");
    }
}
```

Comment: `break` бы в первый метод добавить.

Comment: @Qwertiy Добавил, спасибо!

Comment: Интересно, как вы определили, что второе решение значительно быстрее? Я вообще думаю, что оно медленнее. Да, поиск в `HashSet` быстр, но вы знаете, сколько стоит вставка в него?

Comment: @Андрей Я расчитывал на то, что запросов на поиск будет значительно больше чем добавлений элементов. А если массив будет содержать 1млн элементов то поиск в цикле по всему массиву конечно будет в млн раз медленней.

Comment: Не думаю, что количество элементов в массиве влияет здесь, накладные расходы на один элемент не зависят от их количества

Comment: @Андрей Допустим 1 млн элементов в массиве, и 10 млн запросов поиска. Если делать циклом то будет 10 триллионов сравнений и вычитки элементов массива, сложность квадратичная. Если использовать хэшсет то будет 1 млн добавлений и 10 млн запросов, всего 11 млн более сложных чем в первом случае операций. 10 триллионов элементарных операций будет раз в 10 000 медленней выполняться чем 11 млн в несколько раз более сложных операций.

Comment: В таком случае данные изначально нужно хранить в HashSet, если поиск по ним нам нужен более одного раза