# Упаковка ValueType при использовании IEnumerable

Tags: c#, массивы, .net

Допустим, имеется некий массив, например:

```
int[,] array = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
```

Все массивы реализуют `IEnumerable` (не generic), таким образом, при использовании этого интерфейса все элементы будут упакованы?

Вопрос актуален, например, при использовании `Linq`-операций `Cast<T>()` или `OfType<T>()`:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" " , array.Cast<int>()));
```

Comment: Судя по [исходникам](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,152b93d25e224365) упаковка-распаковка таки будет

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо за ссылку, я тоже думаю что будет, просто сегодня ажиотаж среди переборщиков двумерных массивов. Соответственно даже `foreach (int x in array)` будет приводить к упаковке, так ведь?

Comment: Мне кажется, если это ```foreach (int x in array)``` применить к ```IEnumerable<int>```, то ничего не будет. Если применить к ```IEnumerable``` - то распаковка на лицо

Comment: @tym32167, а `IEnumerable<int>` разве реализуется массивом? Вроде нет же, иначе `Cast` не потребовался бы

Comment: @Андрей я так понял, что вы прозрачно намекаете нам, что с массивом нужно работать только через цикл `for()`, а не foreach()?

Comment: @Bulson, я подозреваю пока что, но всё идёт к этому. И да, с массивом, имеющим более чем одно измерение. С одномерным массивом, на сколько я помню, там хак внедрён и нет упаковки...

Comment: @Андрей не заметил, что вы про двумерные массивы :)

Comment: @tym32167, ага, вопрос именно по массиву, имеющему более одного измерения...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Да, ситуация с многомерными массивами довольно печальная. Такой массив реализует `IEnumerable`, но не реализует `IEnumerable<T>`. А это означает, что любое использование многомерного массива через "призму" `IEnumerable` приведет к упаковке каждого элемента, и использование метода `Enumerable.Cast<T>` - не исключение.

Вот простой бенчмарк (на основе [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/)), который показывает, что это действительно так:

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class MultidimentionalAarrayTests
{
    private int[,] m_multiArray = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    private int[] m_regularArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    [Benchmark]
    public int MultiArrayLast()
    {
        return m_multiArray.Cast<int>().Last();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int RegularArrayLast()
    {
        return m_regularArray.Last();
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
                     Method |        Mean |     Error |    StdDev |  Gen 0 | Allocated |
--------------------------- |------------:|----------:|----------:|-------:|----------:|
             MultiArrayLast | 1,166.97 ns | 23.229 ns | 51.473 ns | 0.0401 |     132 B |
           RegularArrayLast |    51.29 ns |  1.250 ns |  3.686 ns |      - |       0 B |
```

Мы тут видим кучку аллокаций: в первом случае - упакован каждый элемент, итератор в `Cast<T>`, итератор в `Last<T>`. Во втором случае нет аллокаций вообще, поскольку `Last<T>` проверяет, что последовательность реализует `IList<T>` (а одномерный массив его реализует) и сразу же возвращает последний элемент.

Поскольку многомерные массивы не реализуют обобщенный `IEnumerable<T>`, то заставить его сделать это самим мы не можем, но мы можем создать метод расширения, чтобы не использовать `Enumerable.Cast<T>`:

```
public static class MultiDimentionalArrayEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(this T[,] array)
    {
        foreach (var e in array) yield return e;
    }
}
```

Теперь мы можем добавить еще один бенчмарк, чтобы проверить результат:

```
[Benchmark]
public int MultiArrayWithAsEnumerable()
{
    return m_multiArray.AsEnumerable().Last();
}
```

И вот окончательный результат:

```
                     Method |        Mean |      Error |     StdDev |  Gen 0 | Allocated |
--------------------------- |------------:|-----------:|-----------:|-------:|----------:|
             MultiArrayLast | 1,115.45 ns | 31.0145 ns | 90.9603 ns | 0.0401 |     132 B |
           RegularArrayLast |    46.11 ns |  0.1826 ns |  0.1525 ns |      - |       0 B |
 MultiArrayWithAsEnumerable |   161.74 ns |  3.2693 ns |  3.2109 ns | 0.0150 |      48 B |
```

Здесь мы видим, что есть выделение в куче двух итераторов (одного для метода расширения и еще одного для `Enumerable.Last<T>`), но нет упаковок самих элементов.

Comment: А почему вы говорите "придется создать кучу методов расширения для каждого значимого типа"? Такой generic-метод, вроде, дает тот же результат: `public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(this T[,] array)`

Comment: Да, @Андрей, конечно:). Так что вот вам и обобщенное решение: вместо Cast<T> используйте AsEnumerable и это избавит от упаковок;)

Comment: @Андрей Поправил ответ.

Comment: А зачем нужен `where T:struct`?

Comment: Потому что для классов вполне Cast<T> подойдет.

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov но зачем намеренно ограничивать-то? Ваш метод безопаснее чем Cast. А еще может быть случай когда неизвестно класс атм или структура.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Ок, в этом случае можно убрать ограничение. Тут фундаментальных проблем с этим у меня никаких нет:))

Answer (score 8):

При использовании необобщённого `IEnumerable` упаковки, конечно, не избежать.

Но компилятор умный, и в *некоторых* случаях может обойтись без `IEnumerable`. Важный случай — это если объект, по которому производится перечисление, обладает открытым методом `GetEnumerator` с подходящей сигнатурой. В этом случае будет использован именно он.*

Второй важный частный случай (и именно он у нас имеет место) — это массивы. Компилятор знает, как можно более эффективно обходить массивы, и иногда пользуется этим.

Например, вот такая функция

```
static int[,] array = ...;
static void Test()
{
    foreach (var val in array)
        Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```

скомпилировалась так, как будто она была написана следующим образом:

```
int[,] array = Program.array;
int upperBound = array.GetUpperBound(0);
int upperBound2 = array.GetUpperBound(1);
for (int i = array.GetLowerBound(0); i <= upperBound; i++)
{
    for (int j = array.GetLowerBound(1); j <= upperBound2; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(array[i, j]);
    }
}
```

Для случая `Cast<T>`, кажется, оптимизатор не пытается улучшить код для массивов, и таки использует `Cast`. [В коде `Cast<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1023) есть проверка на наличие *типизированного* варианта `IEnumerable<T>` (и в этом случае упаковки бы не было), но массив его не поддерживает. Так что выполняется [итерация по `IEnumerable`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1030) с упаковкой результатов. В последующих версиях языка, возможно, оптимизатор станет умнее (если разработчики сочтут этот случай важным).

---

(Для недоверчивых, вот IL-код:

```
// int[,] array = Program.array;
IL_0000: ldsfld int32[0..., 0...] Test.Program::'array'
IL_0005: stloc.0

// int upperBound = array.GetUpperBound(0);
IL_0006: ldloc.0
IL_0007: ldc.i4.0
IL_0008: callvirt instance int32 [mscorlib]System.Array::GetUpperBound(int32)
IL_000d: stloc.1

// int upperBound2 = array.GetUpperBound(1);
IL_000e: ldloc.0
IL_000f: ldc.i4.1
IL_0010: callvirt instance int32 [mscorlib]System.Array::GetUpperBound(int32)
IL_0015: stloc.2

// i = array.GetLowerBound(0)
IL_0016: ldloc.0
IL_0017: ldc.i4.0
IL_0018: callvirt instance int32 [mscorlib]System.Array::GetLowerBound(int32)
IL_001d: stloc.3

IL_001e: br.s IL_0048 // jump to outer loop check
// loop start (head: IL_0048)
    // j = array.GetLowerBound(1)
    IL_0020: ldloc.0
    IL_0021: ldc.i4.1
    IL_0022: callvirt instance int32 [mscorlib]System.Array::GetLowerBound(int32)
    IL_0027: stloc.s 4

    IL_0029: br.s IL_003f // jump to inner loop check
    // loop start (head: IL_003f)
        // array[i, j]
        IL_002b: ldloc.0
        IL_002c: ldloc.3
        IL_002d: ldloc.s 4
        IL_002f: call instance int32 int32[0..., 0...]::Get(int32, int32)
        IL_0034: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)

        // j++
        IL_0039: ldloc.s 4
        IL_003b: ldc.i4.1
        IL_003c: add
        IL_003d: stloc.s 4

        // j <= upperBound2
        IL_003f: ldloc.s 4
        IL_0041: ldloc.2
        IL_0042: ble.s IL_002b
    // end loop

    // i++
    IL_0044: ldloc.3
    IL_0045: ldc.i4.1
    IL_0046: add
    IL_0047: stloc.3

    // i <= upperBound
    IL_0048: ldloc.3
    IL_0049: ldloc.1
    IL_004a: ble.s IL_0020
// end loop

IL_004c: ret
```

Проверяйте!)

---

*Ссылка на [документацию](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/statements.md#the-foreach-statement):

> - Otherwise, determine whether the type X has an appropriate `GetEnumerator` method:

и только после этого

> - Otherwise, check for an enumerable interface:

Это позволяет, в частности, при итерации по `List<T>` итерировать не по интерфейсу `IEnumerator<T>`, а по [**структуре** `List<T>.Enumerator`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.enumerator?view=netframework-4.7), и тем самым избежать упаковки этой структуры.

Comment: Т.е `Cast` тоже не будет упаковать элементы получается? Или все же будет?

Comment: @Андрей: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: то, что упаковка есть в коде Cast (и даже в его IL, еще не означает, он он будет при реальном выполнении). попробуйте взять memory profiler, и найти в куче те самые обернутые инты. `Enumerable+<CastIterator>d__94<Int32>` в куче будет, а оберток-интов - нет

Comment: @PashaPash: А можно какой-то референсный код? Ну и при перечислении упакованные инты могут быть собраны в первом поколении, или быть вытеснены в стек, допустим (jit уже умеет в escape analysis?). Один лишь результат профайлера как-то у меня не вызывает доверия.

Comment: Чего-то мне кажется, что топик-стартер спрашивал об упаковке элементов, а в ответе речь идет об упаковке итератора...

Comment: @PashaPash Я могу представить, что рантайм сделает escape анализ (как делается в Java), чтобы избежать аллокации итератора. Но: 1. escape анализа в .NET-е нет. 2. Для блока итераторов он был бы не возможен и 3. Догадаться, что элементы упаковывать не нужно нельзя даже с помощью escape анализа.

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov: В ответе приводится пример того, что foreach не работает через необобщённый `IEnumerable` с необходимостью упаковки каждого элемента, как можно было бы предположить, а разворачивает в двойной цикл, в котором упаковка элементов не нужна.

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov: А про упаковку итератора вообще в подстрочном примечании.

Comment: @VladD Сорри. Вопросы сняты:)

Comment: @VladD, у вас ссылки на referencesource протухли. Вообще получается для оптимизации достаточно в методе `CastIterator` заменить `foreach (object obj ...` на `foreach (TResult obj ...`? Интересно, у них BCL на гитхабе выложен, можно было бы merge request подготовить...