# Проверка условия с nullable массивом

Tags: c#, массивы, double, условия

Есть условие, в котором проверяются элементы массива на ноль или null. 
Компилятор выдаёт ошибку: Оператор "&&" невозможно применить к операнду типа "double?" и "double?"

```
if (numArray[0, 0] && numArray[1, 0] && numArray[2, 0] == 0) 
|| (numArray[0, 0] && numArray[1, 0] && numArray[2, 0] == null)
```

Вопросы:

- Как избежать этой ошибки?
- Есть ли способ более короткой записи такого условия?

Comment: Должно быть `if ((numArray[0, 0] == 0 && numArray[1, 0] == 0 && numArray[2, 0] == 0) || (numArray[0, 0] == null && numArray[1, 0] == null && numArray[2, 0] == null))`. Вы `numArray[0, 0]` и `numArray[1, 0]` ни с чем не сравниваете, да и скобок у `if`-а не хватает.

Comment: А что вы имеете ввиду, когда пишете `numArray[0, 0] && numArray[1, 0]`?

Comment: Если хотя бы один элемент равен 0 или null

Comment: @Regent Да, точно, спасибо! А есть ли более короткий способ записи такого условия?

Comment: короче с использованием Linq `if(  numArray.Cast<double?>().All(num => (num==0 || num==null))  )`

Comment: Если покороче, то можно так: `((numArray[0, 0] ?? 0) == 0) || ((numArray[0, 1] ?? 0) == 0) || ((numArray[0, 2] ?? 0) == 0)`

Comment: подозреваю, что вариант когда некоторые `==null` а все другие `==0` вам бы тоже стоит обработать :)

Comment: @Alias как по мне, вариант "либо все ноли, либо все null-ы" вполне имеет право на жизнь.

Comment: @Regent вполне) как ТСу будет угодно.

Comment: Иван, если требуется *>>хотя бы один элемент равен 0 или null* тогда все сравнения через ИЛИ (`||`), соответственно будет `if( numArray.Cast<double?>().Any(num => (num==0 || num==null))`; ваша текущая запись требует равенства 0 либо null одновременно от всех элементов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сравнивать каждое значение с `0` и `null` нужно так:

```
if ((numArray[0, 0] == 0 && numArray[1, 0] == 0 && numArray[2, 0] == 0)
    || (numArray[0, 0] == null && numArray[1, 0] == null && numArray[2, 0] == null))
```

Вариант чуть покороче:

```
var checkedValues = new[] { numArray[0, 0], numArray[1, 0], numArray[2, 0] };

if (checkedValues.All(v => v == 0) || checkedValues.All(v => v == null))
```

---

Если условие не "или все нули, или все null-ы", а "все или нули, или null-ы", то тогда так:

```
if (checkedValues.All(v => v == 0 || v == null))
```

или так:

```
if (checkedValues.All(v => (v ?? 0) == 0))
```

---

И тут я прочитал комментарий "Если хотя бы один элемент равен 0 или null". В этом случае вместо `All` должно быть `Any`:

```
if (checkedValues.Any(v => v == 0 || v == null))
```

Comment: Чуть покороче, но менее читабельно: `if (checkedValues.All(v => (v ?? 0) == 0))
{
}`

Answer (score 2):

Ещё один вариант:

```
checkedValues.Any(v => v.GetValueOrDefault() == 0)
```

с предварительным

```
double?[] checkedValues = { numArray[0, 0], numArray[1, 0], numArray[2, 0] };
```

Если вам нужно проверить *весь* массив `numArray`, это можно укоротить до

```
numArray.Cast<double?>().Any(v => v.GetValueOrDefault() == 0)
```

Comment: Для сведения, не стоит злоупотреблять `Cast<T>` на двумерном массиве - это может создать много накладных расходов на упаковку: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/737194/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Ну это в текущей имплементации. С текущей направленностью на мобильные платформы, я думаю, эту проблему решат рано или поздно.