# Поиск максимального числа которое встречается более одного раза в двухмерном массиве

Tags: c#

Как в двухмерном массиве найти максимальное число которое встречается больше одного раза?

Comment: Отвечающие на этом сайте ставят минусы и закрывают вопросы, если они похожи на ТЗ. Пожалуйста, дополните вопрос [**собственными попытками**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) справиться с заданием. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных на ТЗ и на ДЗ )

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```
int[,] array =
{
    { 3, 1, 2 },
    { 0, 0, 5 },
    { 2, 3, 4 },
};
var max = array.Cast<int>()
               .GroupBy(x => x)
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
               .First(x => x.Count() > 1)
               .Key;
Console.WriteLine(max);
```

Но не забывайте, что все элементы массива будут упакованы: [Упаковка ValueType при использовании IEnumerable](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/737194/218063)