# Можно ли как-нибудь взаимодействовать с двухмерными и более... массивами с помощью LINQ или Array?

Tags: c#

Например, я пробовал вот так (но естественно ничего не получилось): можно ли найти сумму всех четных элементов двумерного массива

```
int[,] a = new int[4, 8];
        Random ran = new Random();
//...    
Array.FindAll(a, i =>i  % 2 == 0).Sum(); //или
    a.Where(i => i % 2 == 0).Sum();
```

Comment: linq может взаимодействовать со всем у кого есть интерфейс `IEnumerable<T>`, у массивов он есть, следовательно и linq к нему можно применять

Comment: [Using Linq with 2D array, Select not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3150678/2881286)

Comment: `a.Cast<int>.Where(i => i % 2 == 0).Sum()` - оно?

Comment: ДА @aepot, спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо  @Grundy

Comment: [linq2d](https://github.com/evilguest/linq2d) - наслаждайтесь.

Comment: Тут немного про linq2d: [Производительность .Net на вычислительных задачах](https://rsdn.org/forum/flame.comp/7858526). ЗЫ: Ахтунг, там в комментах драма - у сипипишников подгорает.

Comment: Ещё про перебор двумерных массивов здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/737194/218063